# I am getting strange value when I tried to calculate the points to draw a circle using diameter and center point

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry, gmap.net

These are very simple inputs and I got the correct center point and diameter from the algorithm called Crystal-Pierce. *Center point* is *0,0* and *diameter* is *2.82...*. 
Ultimate goal is to draw the circle using this on the GmapController, when I tried it with the result, it did not encircle the all convex hull points. 
Thinking about this will be drawn on the map, do I have consider any other factors? like how much GMAp is zoomed in?

**inputs**

```
1,1
1,-1
-1, -1
-1, 1
```

**this is the result I am getting**

```
Lat: 0|| Lon: 0|| diameter: 2.82842712474619
a: 1.4142135623731 || b: 0
a: 1.34499702392791 || b: 0.437016024448821
a: 1.14412280563537 || b: 0.831253875554907
a: 0.831253875554907 || b: 1.14412280563537
a: 0.437016024448821 || b: 1.34499702392791
a: 8.65956056235493E-17 || b: 1.4142135623731
a: -0.437016024448821 || b: 1.34499702392791
a: -0.831253875554907 || b: 1.14412280563537
a: -1.14412280563537 || b: 0.831253875554907
a: -1.34499702392791 || b: 0.437016024448821
a: -1.4142135623731 || b: 1.73191211247099E-16
a: -1.34499702392791 || b: -0.437016024448821
a: -1.14412280563537 || b: -0.831253875554907
a: -0.831253875554907 || b: -1.14412280563537
a: -0.437016024448821 || b: -1.34499702392791
a: -2.59786816870648E-16 || b: -1.4142135623731
a: 0.437016024448821 || b: -1.34499702392791
a: 0.831253875554907 || b: -1.14412280563537
a: 1.14412280563537 || b: -0.831253875554907
a: 1.34499702392791 || b: -0.437016024448821
```

**This is the code for circling**

```
static void Main (string[] args) {
            PlaceOfInterest p1 = new PlaceOfInterest (1, 1, 1, "");
            PlaceOfInterest p2 = new PlaceOfInterest (1, 1, -1, "");
            PlaceOfInterest p3 = new PlaceOfInterest (1, -1, 1, "");
            PlaceOfInterest p4 = new PlaceOfInterest (1, -1, -1, "");
            PlaceOfInterest p5 = new PlaceOfInterest (1, 0, 0, "");
            // PlaceOfInterest p6 = new PlaceOfInterest (1, 2, 2, "");
            List<PlaceOfInterest> list  = new List<PlaceOfInterest>();
            list.Add(p1);
            list.Add(p2);
            list.Add(p3);
            list.Add(p4);
            list.Add(p5);
             // list.Add(p6);
            List<PlaceOfInterest> hull = new List<PlaceOfInterest>();
            hull = ConvexHull.GrahmConvexHull(list);
            SEC.SmallestEnclosingCircle(hull);
            double x = SEC.centerPoint.Latitude;
            double y = SEC.centerPoint.Longitude;
            double diameter = SEC.diameter;
            Console.WriteLine("Lat: {0}|| Lon: {1}|| diameter: {2}", x, y, diameter);
            int segments = 20;

            double seg = Math.PI * 2 / segments;
            double aspect = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < segments; i++)
            {
                double theta = seg * i;
                double radius = SEC.diameter / 2;
                double a = SEC.centerPoint.Latitude + Math.Cos(theta) * radius* aspect;
                double b = SEC.centerPoint.Longitude + Math.Sin(theta) * radius;
                Console.WriteLine("a: {0} || b: {1}", a,b);
            }



        }
```

Comment: What are the units of `SEC.diameter`? I very much doubt that they are in degrees as you can't possibly represent a circle on the earth like that. Consider near the north pole. A circle on the earth is not a circle in lat/long angles.

Comment: If the circle is small enough and you aren't near the equator you might be able to approximate it by finding the approximate angle your circle represents for a cone based at the origin of the sphere. And since sin(x) ~= x for very small x, you might be able to divide your distance by the circumference of the earth and multiply by 360 to get an approximate angle to use in your current incorrect, but maybe good enough, circle code.

Comment: After executing smallest enclosing circle, I will assign the centerpoint and diameter to the variable in SEC class. Center point in this case is *0,0*.  The formula using segments are what I got from stackoverflow to draw the circle on the GMap.

Comment: What is the diameter measured in? meters? kilometers? You need to convert it to an angular measure: `angle = distance / circumference of earth x 2 * PI` and hope your circle is small enough that it's a good approximation. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1218805/31304 for how complex this really is if you want to do it exactly.